# Application only displays images after having them opened in a separate tag

Tags: nginx

An application is served via Nginx for / from an internal server port (configuration see below). Images are then not shown in the web browser. But when displaying an image in a new tab (via context menu of the browser) and the page is reloaded, then the image is shown.

Configuration:

```
location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8007/;

    proxy_redirect      http://127.0.0.1:8007 https://my-url.com;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure about the source of the described problem (I know other web applications where everything works fine with just one simple rule for the whole application), but I could solve it by adding a special rule for the resources (before the "/"-rule):

```
location ~ ^/(assets|images|javascript|js|css|flash|media|static)/  {
    root    /path/to/the/resources/on/the/server/;
    expires 30d;
}
```